# Should the general game identification tag always mark the last installment? (on the specific example of GURPS)

Tags: discussion

Most of the questions tagged [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps) at the moment actually refer to GURPS 4th Edition.
Tasks relevant to 3rd edition only are also tagged [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps), very few questions are tagged [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e) and [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps) both and one single [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11269/why-use-a-pistol-instead-of-a-rifle) is only tagged [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e).

The choice I see are:

- the relevant questions should be retagged [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e) and [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps)
- the relevant questions shoulb be retagged to only [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e)
- the general and 4th edition questions keep the [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps) tag, the [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e) is removed and a [gurps-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-3e) is created for all relevant questions.

The difference between GURPS 3rd and GURPS 4th Edition has been addressed in the Question: [What are the differences between the various editions of GURPS?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/what-are-the-differences-between-the-various-editions-of-gurps)

Comment: If the style of the question is not correct, I'm sorry and please tell me how to do it correctly ;)

Comment: Actually when looking over the questions there is **not a single question** that speciffically only applies to 3rd Edition, but a few that are not really related to a specific edition. [1](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8379/sources-for-officially-published-gurps-monsters) [2](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8014/purchasing-old-gurps-and-other-out-of-print-games-online) [3](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7627/gurps-series-as-compiled-books) [4](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/what-are-the-differences-between-the-various-editions-of-gurps)

Answer (score 4):

The current style we've been going for is that the generic tag is for questions that span editions (mostly meta and settings questions), while edition specific tags are used for edition-specific questions (usually without the umbrella tag).

There are exceptions to this, however. Lately I've seen some retagging of questions tagged with [deathwatch](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deathwatch) (for example) getting the parent [wfrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp) tag added.

In general, I'm not a fan of using the generic tag to mean a specific version. I see a few issues with it:

- It requires a retagging when a new edition comes out (as is about to happen for Dungeons and Dragons).
- The assumed highest edition can be murky. Is Saga edition the latest edition of the d20 Star Wars franchise (same publisher, same licenses, entirely different system)? Or a new franchise on its own? What about games that have crossed publishers? Does West End Games's D6 Star Wars system count as part of the same franchise as WotC's system, or its own? What if the most recent printing of a product is a reprint of a legacy system (I believe both D&D and WoD are going to be in this situation soon)?
- How do meta and settings questions get tagged under this system?

Now, there is a caveat that's pretty important. Some systems don't have the volume to support a full tag structure. In that case, tag them with the lowest level that can be supported (in addition to more specific tags) and include edition detail in the body of the question.

Comment: +1 any system that requires multiple tags is unlikely to be successful.  Rather I'd suggest that we use the tag wiki's to link tags together.

Answer (score 3):

Any attempt to make tags, which are just added by individual posters, be any more complicated or rules-bound is doomed to failure.

If there's not a real problem, leave it be.  Some games have versions close enough (CoC) that tracking revision is pointless busywork. If the poster thinks the version bears on the answers, they'll add one.